# faster mongodb aggregation for $group and $slice each group for huge collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Basically i have a DB to log all record containing: device mac address, record data, and timestamp.

```js
record = {
  mac_address: "0A-1B-2C-3D-4E-5F",
  data: {recordObj},
  timestamp: "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I also have the DB containing device information: device name, device status.

```js
device = {
  name: "Some Name",
  mac_address: "0A-1B-2C-3D-4E-5F",
  status: "Some Status"
}
```

I need to get last nth data for each device, currently, I use mongo DB aggregate method:

```js
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$mac_address",
    data: { $push: "$data" },
  },
  $lookup: {
    from: 'device',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'mac_address',
    as: 'device_detail',
  },
  $project: {
    name: { $arrayElemAt: ["$device_detail.name", 0] },
    mac_address: { $arrayElemAt: ["$device_detail.mac_address", 0] },
    record: { 
      "$slice": [ "$data", 10 ],
    },
  },
}
```

this aggregation work fine, but when I reach million of record collection data, the query takes a long time.

I just need around 10 to 100 last data for each device, is there is a better method to aggregate the data? or better data structuring? or method?

PS: sometimes a device can send thousand of data daily, and another device only sends tens or even ones, so sorting it by time and limiting the record before grouping it make some device not queried as they send it less often than the other one.

TEMPORARY SOLUTION :

I change device model to look like this:

```js
device = {
  name: "Some Name",
  mac_address: "0A-1B-2C-3D-4E-5F",
  status: "Some Status"
  record: [] // this only store 100 latest record
}
```

then everytime I create new record, I edit device.record and i also add the record to record collection.

Comment: You can use $slice in the $push operator.

Comment: Also, store mac addresses as 64-bit integers.

Comment: I've tried to $limit it first before $group it, but it makes some device is missing as it is stacked by the other devices' new record.

Comment: What does $limit have to do with anything?

Comment: ah sorry.. i misread your $slice with $limit.

i've tried:
```{
  _id: "$mac_address",
  data: {
    $slice: [
      {$push: "$data"}, 2
    ]
  }
}
```
but it resulting error: The $slice accumulator is a unary operator

Comment: See $push documentation for correct syntax.

Comment: i can't find details about $slice in $push (aggregate), here is the resource i read : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/index.html

Comment: i don't think there is more optimization required in pipeline stages, you can remove `$arrayElemAt` for `mac_address` because you have already in `_id` and provide indexing on `mac_address` field or store mac_address as 64 bit integers.